# how to determine (using java code) if a web page is HTML5 (or older version of HTML)

Tags: version, html

I want to determine the version of HTML of a web page. How do I do this in a Google App Engine Java application? (Or even a desktop java application?)

Comment: HTML documents are, as of HTML5, officially versionless.

Comment: Besides @Alohci's remark: There are far to many factors that would determin the "HTML version" of a web page. And considering that the majority of the web pages out there don't use correct HTML in the first place, it's virtually impossible. You'll need to explain your goal better. Are you considering any or only specific web pages? What do you need the version for?

Comment: Why is the intended version of the page significant to you?  Can't you just grab the `DOCTYPE`?

Comment: I am creating a software that parses through various elements of a web page (like h1 headings/h2..h6 headings/bold body text, meta tags) and gives a set of recommendations, to make that site rank high for a specified search phrase. I have already identified an existing parser which can parse through HTML5 documents... but I need some way to identify a web page as HTML5 or older...

Comment: If you are parsing arbitrary web sites, you'll need a tag soup parser (one that can parse broken HTML) anyway. Such a parser will work with HTML5, too, so it doesn't matter if a page is HTML5 or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the comments have mentioned, there isn’t much of a hard-and-fast difference between an “HTML5” HTML page and an “older” HTML page. It’s all HTML. Much of the point of HTML5 as a standard is to document how browsers already treat HTML, rather than specify new stuff (aside from tags with different names, and JavaScript APIs).

If a page uses the HTML5 doctype (`<!DOCTYPE html>`), that’s a pretty good indication that the author intended it to be HTML5. But as the comments have mentioned, you just need a decent HTML parser — it’ll suck up older HTML and HTML5 alike, because they’re effectively the same thing as far as parsing goes.

I’ve very little experience with HTML parsers, but as robertc suggested in his comment, you might try http://about.validator.nu/htmlparser/.

Comment: [Also relevant](http://about.validator.nu/htmlparser/), since the OP mentioned Java.

Comment: @robertc: heck yes — I was thinking I should have noted that I have hardly any experience using HTML parsers, hence my lack of suggestions.