# How to identify HTML5

Tags: html

Is there anyway to determine whether an HTML file was written in HTML5?

Comment: If it runs in IE6 it's not HTML5.   ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to determine (using java code) if a web page is HTML5 (or older version of HTML)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411408/how-to-determine-using-java-code-if-a-web-page-is-html5-or-older-version-of-h)

Comment: I have this code: `<ol reversed><li><center>item 1</center></li>              <li><center>item 2</center></li></ol>` with `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the start, and it works as expected without errors - a centered, reversed list. However, if I am using HTML5, the <center> tag should not work. What version am I using?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

<sub>oversimplified</sub>
If it uses an [HTML5 doctype](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/syntax.html#the-doctype), it's HTML5.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 47):

HTML 5 websites will not have a reference to the DTD in the doctype. Thus, the doctype tag at the top of the file will look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Instead of one of these:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
```

You could also check if any HTML5 tags are used...

Comment: Thanks for adding the INSTEAD of section.  This should be the answer IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

1) Check `<!DOCTYPE html>`
at the start of the file

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>A blank HTML5 page</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
      </head>
      <body>
      </body>
    </html>
```

2) Detect certain HTML5 only elements such as Canvas.

Comment: An HTML4 page cannot be an HTML5 page, by definition in the [spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/syntax.html#the-doctype). Additionally, detecting an invalid HTML4 element, such as `canvas`, in an HTML4 page does not make the page an HTML5 page, it just means that it's an invalid HTML4 page.

Answer (score 3):

If a page uses the HTML5 doctype `(<!DOCTYPE html>)`, you can determine it as a html5.